# How to sort multi dimensional array of objects in php?

Tags: php, json

I have is array that needs sorting dynamically in php, each name should avoid duplicate but with associates dates. Example  "Player": "[{"date": "2022/09/05", "+"visit_total": 1}, {"date": "2022/09/06", "+"visit_total": 0}, {"date": "2022/09/07", "+"visit_total": 1}]" etc....

```
^ array:28 [
  0 => {#638
    +"name": “Player”
    +"role_id": 1
    +"date": "2021/04/29"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "3"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2021/04/29", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}, {"week": "2021/04/29", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}, {"week": "2021/04/29", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }
  1 => {#639
    +"name": “Player2”
    +"role_id": 1
    +"date": "2022/03/26"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "1"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2022/03/26", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }
  2 => {#640
    +"name": “Player”
    +"role_id": 3
    +"date": "2022/01/20"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "4"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2022/01/20", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}, {"week": "2022/01/20", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}, {"week": "2022/01/20", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}, {"week": "2022/01/20", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }

  3 => {#657
    +"name": "Player2”
    +"role_id": 2
    +"date": "2022/06/08"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "1"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2022/06/08", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }
  4 => {#658
    +"name": "Player”
    +"role_id": 2
    +"date": "2022/07/29"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "1"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2022/07/29", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }
  5 => {#659
    +"name": “Player3”
    +"role_id": 2
    +"date": "2022/09/05"
    +"visit_1": "0"
    +"visit_total": "1"
    +"weekly_history": "[{"week": "2022/09/05", "visit_1": 0, "visit_total": 1}]"
  }
]
```

Comment: Replace the keys of your array: Use `array_map` to build an array of keys like that *YYYYMMDDname* or *name-YYYYMMDD*, then use `array_combine` to produce an array with the new keys and your original array as values. Finally use `ksort`.

Comment: Please you elaborate with sample ?